# Excel: How to get the occurrence of a sequence inside a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]I am trying to get statistics about disease occurrence inside my table.
The column containing the code for each disease is like "I10" in CIM-10 international coding system. Each cell can contain one or multiple codes as shown in the picture attached.
The example for statistics is like so:

| Disease category | Occurrence |
| --- | --- |
| From I00 to I30 | 01. |
| From I31 to I99 | 00. |

Now for simple disease category like k00 to K99 it was easy using countif (array, "*K*")

But if i wnt to get a sub section of I from 00 to 30 i couldn't find a way.

Can anyone please help

Comment: Can you post some example data so we can reproduce what you mean?

Comment: Would this be close to what you mean? `=LET(a,TEXTSPLIT(A2,," "),s,RIGHT(INDEX(a,2),2)+0,e,RIGHT(INDEX(a,4),2)+0,MAP(s,e,LAMBDA(x,y,LET(s,"I"&TEXT(SEQUENCE(1+y-x,,x),"00"),SUM(MMULT(--(TOROW($K$1:$K$9)=s),SEQUENCE(ROWS($K$1:$K$9),,1,0)))))))`

Comment: Sorry i did post a picture of my table but was rejected, i re-uploaded it again now

Comment: So, are you searching in column G, or is that what you're using to search, or is that not even used? Your question is very unclear.

Comment: I am looking in the Column G for the number of occurrences of one of the codes between I00 and I59 and reporting the results in another sheets called reports

Comment: So `I24.9` counts as `I24`?

Comment: Yes , I24.9 is just a variation of the main disease I24 , so in my statistics i will count all I24.X

Comment: Use left() with find() to get the characters before the "." ie "I24" from "I24.X"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I built it in small, but I think you need to cut the formula into separate formulas if the list in column G contains many rows (which I suspect).

The formula below flattens all the values in column G to the length of 3. 2 values in one cell get converted to two cells. The flattened column is stored as `g`. (Power Query may be advisable to accomplish that instead).

Next the value in `A2` is split into separate strings. Each 2nd and 4th string is used to get the start number `s` and the end number `e`. The letter (1st character) from the 2nd string is added to a sequence from the start to the end number and the values of this array are checked to occur in the `g`-array. Mmult sums the occurrences.

```
=LET(g, REDUCE( , $G$2:$G$5,
        LAMBDA(a, b,
               VSTACK(a,
                      IFERROR(LEFT(TEXTSPLIT(b,," "),3),"")))),
     a, TEXTSPLIT(A2,," "),
     s, +RIGHT(INDEX(a,2),2),
     e, +RIGHT(INDEX(a,4),2),
     MAP(   s, e,
     LAMBDA(x, y,
            LET( s, LEFT(INDEX(a,2),1)&TEXT(SEQUENCE(1+y-x,,x),"00"),
SUM(MMULT(--(TOROW(g)=s),SEQUENCE(ROWS(g),,1,0)))))))
```

[image]

**Edit;** Better version where it looks for the text in the rows of column g.
This formula returns 1 if the same number is repeated in the same cell (not sure if that occurs). The previous version would return the times it is found within that cell.

This formula performs better than the previous;

```
=LET(g,TOCOL(G:G,1),a,TEXTSPLIT(A2,," "),s,+RIGHT(INDEX(a,2),2),e,+RIGHT(INDEX(a,4),2),MAP(s,e,LAMBDA(x,y,LET(s,LEFT(INDEX(a,2),1)&TEXT(SEQUENCE(1+y-x,,x),"00"),SUM(MMULT(--(ISNUMBER(FIND(TOROW(s),g))),SEQUENCE(ROWS(s),,1,0)))))))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, i tried it and it gave me 0 on all codes so there must be something i am doing wrong

Comment: I used Range G2:G5, change it to the actual situation (and add $ to lock the row 
umbers: `G$2:G$5` so dragging the formula down won't shift the range). Also if A2 is not the same format as presented in your question it will not work.

Comment: Updated the second formula to filter column G values using `TOCOL(G:G,1)`

Answer (score 1):

From your examples it looks as though an alphanumeric comparison like this would be enough:

```
=COUNTIFS(E$2:E$3,">="&INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(A2," "),2),E$2:E$3,"<="&INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(A2," "),4))
```

[image]

But if some cells only contain a single code without 'From' and 'to' you would have to add this as a condition like this maybe:

```
=IF(LEFT(A2,4)="From",COUNTIFS(E$2:E$3,">="&INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(A2," "),2),E$2:E$3,"<="&INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(A2," "),4)),COUNTIF(E$2:E$3,A2))
```

**EDIT**

As far as I can see from the screenshot there is no separator between the codes so you have to split them on the occurrence of a letter. It's bit awkward to implement, but you could split the data like this:

```
=REDUCE("",G2:G5,LAMBDA(ar,cr,VSTACK(ar,
       TEXTSPLIT(REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(LEN(cr)),LAMBDA(a,c,a&IF(MID(cr,c,1)>"A"," ","")&MID(cr,c,1))),," ",TRUE)
)))
```

Unfortunately you can no longer use countifs without a helper column because the result is an array not a range so you would have to use sum/sumproduct.

So putting the two formulas together:

```
=LET(lower,INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(K2," "),2),
     upper,INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(K2," "),4),
     data,REDUCE("",G$2:G$5,LAMBDA(ar,cr,VSTACK(ar,
            TEXTSPLIT(REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(LEN(cr)),LAMBDA(a,c,a&IF(MID(cr,c,1)>="A"," ","")&MID(cr,c,1))),," ",TRUE)))),
     SUM((data>=lower)*(data<=upper))
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank for your help, but that's supposing there is only one code I10 in cells in the column codes

Comment: I see. So there are sometimes one and sometimes two codes in your screenshot - can there be more than two?

Comment: Anyway one approach would be to transform the data by splitting multiple codes so there is only one code per line - then you could just apply my simple method. I will think about how you would actually do that. I take it that you have quite a few rows of data?

Comment: Yes, as shown above in the picture, some cells do contain 3 codes. It goes up to 4k rows

Answer (score 0):

[image: snapshot]

So first of all thank you all for pitching in, your answers were very inspiring.
Second, from what i understood part of the problem was the first cell format "From X20 to X50" so i had to modify the formula for each cell instead of making it automatically.
Thirdly, each of your solutions inspired me to the following formulas:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--IFERROR(IF(VALUE(MID('VP AC 2023'!G:G,FIND("H",'VP AC 2023'!G:G)+1,2))<=59,1,0),0))
```

Where : 1- 'VP AC 2023'!G:G is the column i am looking inside for disease code
2- iferror is there to catch any empty cells or doesn't conform to my condition
3- value(mid(,find("H" : to look for the start of the code "H" if it exist and then get the next 2 characters after
4- Compare the value of the then found 2 characters to my condition upper 59 ( or any condition i would like ) or lower 59 .
And it works as shown in the attached snapshot
Thank you all